# Firefox SDK: how to automatically place the addon version inside a html page at compilation time

Tags: firefox-addon, build-automation, firefox-addon-sdk

I am making an add-on using the Firefox SDK 1.14.

Every time I make a new version of the addon, I have to change the "version" value of the `packaje.json` file.

In a HTML page inside my addon, called `index.html` which I use with [addon-page module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/addon-page.html), I'd like to show the addon version. The only way I know to show it, is to **manually** edit the file before I run `cfx xpi`. And because I have a horrible memory, I always forget to change it...

Is there any automated way to, just before compile the .xpi file, update the file version in my `index.html` page?

By the way, I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addon `version` is accessible via the [`self`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/self.html) module.

```
var {name, id, version} = require("sdk/self");
```

Then you can set the [`contentScriptOptions`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-worker.html#contentScriptOptions) property when attaching a content script to your html file.

```
var self=require("sdk/self");
var tabs=require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.open({
  url: self.data.url("index.html"),
  onReady: function(tab){
    var pageWorker=tab.attach({
      contentScriptFile: self.data.url("contentscript.js"),
      contentScriptOptions: {addonID: self.id}
    });
  }
});
```

From within the content script, access the contents of `contentScriptOptions` (above) like so:

```
var id = self.options.addonID;
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm actually using PageMod to pass variables to the script. I don't why I did not find the _version_ property.